# I want to display string of words and numbers seperated by slash with the word count and the sum of all numbers

Tags: java

I am having trouble with java. I want to get input from the user that has words and numbers and the output would be to seperate each word or number with a slash and display the word count and the sum of all the numbers listed

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class split{
public static void main(String []args) {
    String word;
    int wordCount = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a string with number");

    word= input.nextLine();
    String array[] = word.split("/");
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    wordCount = input.nextInt();    

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (Pattern.matches("\\d+", array[i])){
          sum +=Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
          wordCount++;
      } 

    }

    System.out.println("is the number of words"+"/"+ wordCount+ " and the sum of the numbers is" + sum);

    input.close();

}

}
```

What I am getting now is:

```
is the number of words/10 and the sum of the numbers is0
```

I want the output to be like this for example

```
hello/10/how/are/10/you
the word count is : 4
the sum of numbers: 20
```

Comment: "I am having trouble with java" what trouble? there's no question in your question.

Comment: Thanks for posting your code. What does it do? Presumably it doesn't do what you want, but what happens? What output are you expecting, and what output are you getting from your code?

Comment: please, add example

Comment: please add example inputs and expected outputs

Comment: use ascii code, you can solve easily

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a manner that invalidates existing answers. If you want to ask another question, post another one (but make sure it is on-topic first, because your last edit changed your question into off-topic)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
String s = "hello 10 how are 10 you";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<word>[a-zA-Z]+)|(?<num>\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

int nwords, sum;
nwords = sum = 0;

while (m.find()){
    if (m.group("word") != null){
        nwords++;
    } else if (m.group("num") != null) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group("num"));
    }
}

System.out.println(String.join("/", s.split(" ")));
System.out.println("the word count is : "+nwords+"\nthe sum of numbers: "+sum);

/* Output:
how/10/how/are/10/you
the word count is : 4
the sum of numbers: 20 */
```

Comment: How about separating them with slash such as if I entered hey how are you 10 30 40 it would display hey/how/are/you /10/30/40

Comment: @user290281, if you want to format the string when you enter ```how are you 10 30 40```, just print like this ```String.join("/", s.split(" "))```

Answer (score 0):

Sweet and simple:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class split{
public static void main(String []args) {
    String word;
    int wordCount = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a string with number");
    word= input.nextLine();

    for(String s : word.split(" ")){
        int i;
        try {
            i = Integer.parseInt(s);
            sum += i;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            wordCount ++;
        }
    } 

    System.out.println("\n"+word.trim().replaceAll(" ","/"));
    System.out.println("the word count is : "+ wordCount+ "\nthe sum of numbers: " + sum);
    input.close();    
}
}
```

This would do the job :)